# Yacc Cannot find YY_CURRENT_BUFFER

Tags: c, bison, lex, flex-lexer

I am following the other examples on this site about how to parse a string with flex:

```
yy_scan_string(string);
yylex();
yyparse(); 
yy_delete_buffer( YY_CURRENT_BUFFER );
```

line 4 gives the problem it says

```
 error: ‘YY_CURRENT_BUFFER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I also don't get YY_BUFFER_STATE, by the way I am calling them from the bison file (.y), so they should be available. 
I am not sure why it is not finding the typedefs. I didn't come up with anything on the first dozen links on google  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Gotta include that header file...

Comment: running yacc generates an yy.h file.

Comment: @H2CO3 I didn't get any file yy.h generated from bison.

Comment: I retagged this as "gnu-Flex" Because I don't think it has anything to do w/ the Adobe/Apache Flex Framework.

Comment: @yzernik Roll over the tags. gnu-Flex is "Flex (The Fast Lexical Analyzer)" and Flex is "Flex is a framework for rapid Rich Internet Application development which runs on Flash Player or Adobe Air."  I've re-tagged other questions on the Lexical Analyzer to gnu-Flex; but if you feel they should be categorized differently, feel let me know so I will not categorize things incorrectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`YY_CURRENT_BUFFER` and `YY_BUFFER_STATE` are defined by flex, not bison, so they're defined (and used) in the `lex.yy.c` file generated by flex.  So you can only access them from the `.l` file, not from the `.y` file.

If you want to access them in a bison grammar, the easiest way is to encapsulate the use of them in a small function you define in the 3rd section of the `.l` file.  Then you call that function from the `.y` file or any other source file.